# Junit5's @CsvFileSource annotation not working with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I'm running a set of tests with Junit 5.
They work correctly if they are launched by Maven, but I cannot run them properly in Eclipse.

Apparently the problem is that Eclipse does not consider correctly the parameters of the annotation @CsvFileSource.

Test:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvFileSource(resources = INPUT_FILE_NAME, numLinesToSkip=1, delimiter=';')
public void testSpot(
        String crossCcy,
        @ConvertWith(LocalDateConverter.class) LocalDate date,
        @ConvertWith(LocalDateConverter.class) LocalDate expectedSpot
    ) throws JFxLibException, IOException {
    FxDateCalculator calculator = FxDateCalculator.newInstance(crossCcy);
    LocalDate spotDate = calculator.getSpotDate(date);
    Assertions.assertEquals(expectedSpot, spotDate, "Cross " + crossCcy + ", date=" + date + ",");
}
```

Mvn:

```
$ mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
....
Running com.fx.jfxlib.calc.date.FxDateCalculatorTest
Tests run: 572, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.406 sec - in com.fx.jfxlib.calc.date.FxDateCalculatorTest
....

Results :

Tests run: 2274, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 22.619 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-26T11:38:45+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Eclipse:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Error resolving parameter at index 1
    at org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTestParameterResolver.resolveParameter(ParameterizedTestParameterResolver.java:63)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameter(ExecutableInvoker.java:207)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:174)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:116)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:110)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$0(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:85)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.lambda$execute$2(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:86)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:36)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "date"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:828)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDate(DateTimeFormatter.java:772)
    at com.bancaimi.fx.jfxlib.test.util.converter.LocalDateConverter.convert(LocalDateConverter.java:19)
    at org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTestParameterResolver.resolveParameter(ParameterizedTestParameterResolver.java:60)
    ... 98 more
```

My csv input has headers (but Eclipse does not skip the header line)

```
cross;date;expected spot
EURUSD;09/12/2015;11/12/2015
EURUSD;04/12/2015;08/12/2015
```

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen:
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200

Comment: Is `INPUT_FILE_NAME` a relative or absolute path? If relative, make sure the _Working directory_ is correctly set in the launch configuration (in the tab _Arguments_).

Comment: It is a relative path, and the resource is in the classpath.
From Javadoc: ```The CSV classpath resources to use as the sources of arguments; must not be empty.```
In fact the file is found and read, I just get an exception while reading the parameters

Comment: I see. [`numLinesToSkip`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/pull/1156) exists from the beginning of JUnit 5, so a possible explanation would be that you use a prerelease of JUnit 5 in your Java build path (as the issue is caused by JUnit code, not by Eclipse code). Unfortunately you are using a very old Eclipse version, without the _Show Command Line_ feature, which would be helpful here.

Comment: Thanks @howlger, you are right. I was using a Junit5 version without that parameter.
Actually it was a release version (5.0.0), but it didn't contain `numLinesToSkip`

Comment: Great, in the current Javadoc there is [no _Since_ at `numLinesToSkip`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/CsvFileSource.html), so I assumed by mistake it was already supported by JUnit 5.0. Anyhow, problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved.

Eclipse Oxygen uses by default `org.junit.jupiter.api_5.0.0`, which does not contain `numLinesToSkip` parameter in `CsvFileSource` annotation.

My Maven dependency had version `5.1.0`, which contains this parameter. That's why it worked properly. Upgrading Eclipse to 2018-12 (`org.junit.jupiter.api_5.3.1`) made the deal for me.

Comment: I would even recommend updating to the latest Eclipse 2019-03, as JUnit 5 support has been further improved. ;)